# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (33554431) has been exceeded

Tags: asp.net, web-services

My client application is calling a web service, everything works fine, except a function call always throw this error (The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (33554431) has been exceeded.)

I have tried to increase the maxBufferSize in the app.config file of my client application to 335544310, but it did not help solving this problem.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpsEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="33554431" maxBufferPoolSize="33554431" maxReceivedMessageSize="33554431" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
                     transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="33554431" maxArrayLength="33554431" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://api.smartmailpro.com/2.0/API.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpsEndpoint" contract="SmartMailProApi.API" name="basicHttpsEndpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I suspect that there are two possibilities

1) The value that I am using is too large
2) I need to perform the same update to the server web services as well

Could anyone point me to the right direction, please?

What are the real purposes of following three parameters :

```
 maxBufferSize="33554431" 
 maxBufferPoolSize="33554431" 
 maxReceivedMessageSize="33554431"
```

Comment: it seems you are sending to big message

Comment: Hi Pranay, thanks. Would you recommand me to increase the value of maxBufferSize of the web services?

Comment: You are absoultely right, maybe this method is getting too large data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enlarge the value of the maxBufferSize to 2147483647, and solved the problem.